# What sites are running on my ((very) old) apache

Tags: apache-1.3

I've got this server that an apache server on which I want to modify a website.

The site is up, the apache processes are running I just need to modify a single line of the website.

Right now when I modify the files I think apache uses to host the website, nothing changes, even after apache restarts.

What is an easy way of finding out what websites are running on my apache server and what files this website pushes to the end user ?

Here is the return of my `apachectl status` command

```
user:server.domain.com> apachectl status

             Apache Server Status for server.domain.com



  Server Version: Oracle HTTP Server Powered by Apache/1.3.22 (Unix)
   mod_plsql/3.0.9.8.5d mod_fastcgi/2.2.12 mod_perl/1.25 mod_oprocmgr/1.0
   Server Built: Apr 26 2002 21:53:26
     _________________________________________________________________

   Current Time: Monday, 18-Jul-2016 16:02:31 EDT
   Restart Time: Monday, 18-Jul-2016 05:00:02 EDT
   Parent Server Generation: 0
   Server uptime: 11 hours 2 minutes 29 seconds
   Total accesses: 266 - Total Traffic: 706 kB
   CPU Usage: u.15 s.233333 cu0 cs0 - .000964% CPU load
   .00669 requests/sec - 18 B/second - 2717 B/request
   1 requests currently being processed, 9 idle servers
__W_______......................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing, "." Open slot with no current
   process
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `apachectl -S` or `httpd -S` to see a list of defined virtual hosts and the configuration files in which they are defined.

Comment: Here is what I get when I run these commands (thanks for your help !) http://pastebin.com/mkNAined

Comment: Help? how do I find a working way of executing those commands ?

Comment: OK, your system is too old for that. You'll have to go looking for the config files yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about httpd.conf ?
anyhow I managed to run a find on the server and modifed the wanted file.
Still, it would have been fun to run that -S command.
For your info, this server is an HP TRU64 ;)